# Replcae inner space in Python

Tags: python

Iam new to Python, And I need to remove space between string and a digit only not between two strings.

eg:

Input : Paragraph 25 is in documents and paragraph number in another file.

Output : Paragraph25 is in documents and paragraph number in another file.

How this can be done in Python ? I tried regex

```
re.sub("paragraph\s[a-z]", "paragraph[a-z]", Input)
```

But its not working.

Comment: It helps if you post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Regexs are your friends

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 >>> re.sub(r'\s+(\d+)', r'\1', 'Program 25 is fun')
'Program25 is fun'
```

That might work in a pinch. I'm not the most familiar with regexes, so hopefully someone who is can chime in with something more robust.

Basically we match on whitespace succeeded by numbers and remove it.